# Как получить объект на сайте, используя beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Я хочу спарсить при помощи beautifulsoup перевод на сайте Google-переводчика (для примера хочу перевести слово overflow на русский). Но при вводе ссылки 
https://translate.google.com.ua/?hl=ru&tab=TT#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=ru&text=overflow

я получаю стандартный HTML Google-переводчика, в котором нет

`<div class="text-dummy">overflow</div>`

Вот html-код в браузере:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я выводил в консоль весь HTML сайта и пытался сделать поиск в консоли, чтобы удостовериться, есть ли вообще такой объект - но, к сожалению, это не дало результатов.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://translate.google.com.ua/?hl=ru&tab=TT#view=home&op=translate&sl=ru&tl=en&text=overflow'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Подскажите, что я упустил и как получить html-код с уже обработанной информацией на сервере?

Comment: Нужен движок на javascript: используйте selenium или, думаю, поможет https://github.com/psf/requests-html . Там, при загрузке страницы самого html меньше, чем кода на javascript

Comment: @gil9red, я сегодня специально посмотрел в сторону beautifulsoup, чтобы отказаться от selenium-a) Слишком большая нагрузка получается для моего проекта

Comment: Лучше отказаться от парсинга и попробовать работать с модулем, который умеет это делать, например `googletrans`: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5280046aefa801c9b233aebb14bf3a21990129ad/googletrans__examples/hello_world.py#L18

Comment: @gil9red, дело в том, что я уже использую в своем проекте эту библиотеку и мне нужно было вообще спарсить транскрипцию перевода (а в вопросе я привел небольшой пример просто с переводом слова; с транскрипцией - задача аналогичная моему вопросу). Не подскажите, каким способом это можно сделать?)